# Best way to label picker with multiple components?

Tags: labels, standards, spinner

I have a 3-component iOS picker where the user picks the section, row, and seat of a venue. What is considered the best practice for labeling the components? I also don't want a valid default selection (e.g. "101", "A", "1").

I've thought of two options:

1. Put the labels above the picker with "(none)" as the default selection for each component.
2. Put the labels inside the picker as the default selections: "(Section)", "(Row)", and "(Seat)".

I'm thinking option 2 is best, but I'd like some feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a mockup of both options? I'm having trouble visualizing your concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Your case looks like booking a seat for a venue. 
For these kind of flows I would suggest use the actual model of the venue.
Reason.

- It help user to visualise the venue
- You can easily show which seats are booked and not available or only available.
- It reduce the time of seat selection

Try this.

[image]

Comment: Makes sense.I think you can add the position too here like - Exits, Elevators etc

Comment: Great thought vaibhav ...

Answer (score 0):

Choosing between two options you provided, option one is better. That a classic case of having labels as placeholders inside the fields. Right after user enters something he looses context of what's where. It may work on some simple systems (e.g. login forms), but obviously not complex solutions like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1, but change the default picker text to "Choose section", "Choose row", "and "Choose seat."

This gives the user a clear call to action. Do this thing! "None" makes the user a consider the null state and realize they have to switch out of it. "Choose" talks right at 'em.

Comment: Thanks. I like that. I need to see if there's room since little space is needed for the actual selections. It may be enough to put "Choose your seat:" followed by "Section", "Row", and "Seat" above the picker components.